# resize/scale canvas for pdf via print.css file

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

when saving site as pdf (phantomjs), i specify in my print css file that my canvas is supposed to be 100% width height.

```
canvas {
   max-width: 100%!important;
   max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

However in the pdf, it's scaled wrong and looks stretched. 
From reading various post i learned that setting height/width attr in css for canvas is a no go, and you must specify it directly in the canvas tag.
source : https://www.kirupa.com/html5/resizing_html_canvas_element.htm

How can i deal with this to get a proper looking canvas in my pdf format ?

Comment: To avoid pixel distortion, don't scale the canvas with CSS. Instead set the canvasElement.width and canvasElement.height.

Comment: what if its only to be resized in the pdf format - how would you go about doing that if it can't be done through the print css file ? thanks for your effort.

Comment: Set the canvas **element** width & height: `canvasElement.width=desiredWidth; canvasElement.height=desiredHeight;`. If you need your drawings to be larger on your canvas you can proportionally scale the canvas with `context.scale(horizontally,vertically)` For example to scale your canvas drawings by 150% you can do this: `var scale=1.5; context.scale(scale,scale)`.